# android: layout inflater

Tags: android, layout, view

In my layout I want to add a images on screen when user clicks on a button. The number of images depend on the user i.e decided at runtime. How can layout inflater be used for this purpose such that my view changes dynamically with the user input.

Comment: use a listview or gridview

Comment: i am confused so as to how will gridview work if number of images to be added is also decided during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think in your case Layout inflater is not necessary  you can create imageviews dynamically in java and add it to your main layout.

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLL);
while(count<yourusersimagesNeeded)
{
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Activity);
// set src and other attrs
ll.addView(imageView);
count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to this, how will i be able to dynamically add it to the main layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add views to a `ViewGroup` with the `addView(View)` method. See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Roughly:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Activity);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image); // or setImageBitmap, etc
myRootView.addView(imageView);
```

Where the new view is displayed depends on the layout type of the ViewGroup it was added to. See the docs on [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) for more information now how to dynamically position a view.

Answer (score 0):

Say your activity layout is one LinearLayout "main_layout", now you can add your infalted image view dynamically using below code.

```
LinearLayout main_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
LayoutInflater mInflater;
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this);


ImageView image = (ImageView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_image_view, null);
main_container.addView(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need layout inflater. You just need to create imageview on button click and add it to layout below or above your button(or wherever you want to add), you can also remove added images if you add listener to imageview i.e. on click imageview remove from layout.